# Printing plots after a for loop

Tags: r

I am generating plots in a for loop in this way

```
p <- vector("list", 10)

for (i in 1:10){

 p[[i]] <- plot (…)


}
```

How can I print them all together in the same graph, using something like

```
plot(p1,more =F)
plot(p2,more =T)
.
.
.
```

but with a loop?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need  something like

```
 par(new=T)
```

http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/layout.html

Comment: Thanks, this is like more=TRUE in the print call. How can I make it a for loop?

Answer (score 0):

The first call must be to `plot` and the subsequent calls must be to either `lines` or `points`.

Here is one way of making this happen.

```
first = T
for (i in 1:10){

if (first) {
 plot (…)
 first = F;
}
else {
   lines(...)
}


}
```

Comment: Thanks, but since I am using ggplot I can't do this

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(p[[1]],p[[2]],...)
```

Then you will have all your plots together.